# Error: HTTP 0 Error: HTTP 0 http://127.0.0.0:7212/

Tags: php, json, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Noob here, I have a VPS with Ubuntu 14.04, when I try to make a request by POST that message appears.

I do not know much about the subject, but I'm trying to get data through json

Comment: Did you install a webserver such as apache?

Comment: Yes, Install apache, php5.5, ... (LAMP)

Comment: I just noticed that your first post the url for local host is wrong. It's 127.0.0.1

Comment: You are amazing! Is work now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

127.0.0.0 doesn't correspond to you're loopback address.

By default the loopback address is '127.0.0.1', this resolves to the hostname 'localhost'.

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost